# Silverlight binding using stringformat to display blank for 0

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, converters, string-formatting

Is it possible to somehow make 0 values appear blank using the StringFormat property, or is it acheivable by writing a custom converter?

The value is of double type.

Input is 0, output should be "". But when input is other than 0 then output should equal input.

EDIT:

I tried :

```
sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colBidQty" Header="Bid Qty" Binding="{Binding BidPrice.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat="{}{0:#}"}" Foreground="Black" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=BidPrice.ToolTip}" ToolTipService.Placement="Right" />
```

Comment: can you give an example? what is input and what you want as an output.

Comment: for eg- double d = 1010101010;       output=1 1 1 1 1 double d=111111 output=111111...is this what you want..?

Comment: No, not replace all zeros, the value will be just one 0, then replace with "", else do not.

Comment: their will be b only one zero and you want to replace that 0 with a blank space...right..?? (input)10111-(output)1 111

Comment: @MuhammadA, did you try `{}{0:#}`?

Comment: @dkozl I tried that but seems like the syntax needs escaping somehow.

Comment: @MuhammadA, try without inner ": `Binding="{Binding BidPrice.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:#}}"`

Comment: @dkozl says "Unexpected Token after end of Markup Extension." but seems to be better as there are no squiggly lines in the editor.

Comment: @MuhammadA, it seems to be different in Silverlight. Give this a try: `Binding="{Binding BidPrice.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#}'}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up comments, you can specify `StringFormat` as `{0:#}` which will replace 0 with empty string:

```
Binding="{Binding BidPrice.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#}'}"
```

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)